# Fire and forget with ServiceStack's AsyncServiceBase

Tags: servicestack

I have following service

```
public class AppService : AsyncServiceBase<EvaluateStock>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public override object ExecuteAsync(EvaluateStock request)
    {
        // this will block the incoming http request 
        // unitl task is completed

        // long computation
        // Bus.Publish(result)
    }
}
```

which gets called by different consumers following way

```
POST
http://srv1/app/json/asynconeway/EvaluateStock
```

Using asynconeway I was assuming that it will allow me to achieve fire and forget as WCF does with IsOneWay. But seems is not the case.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: I forgot to mention I do not need to return to the consumers anything at the end of ExecuteAsync

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[AsyncServiceBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/AsyncServiceBase.cs#L17) has been deprecated as [ExecuteAsync](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/ServiceBase.cs#L307) is now in ServiceBase which is what gets called when a request is made to **/asynconeway/XXX** pre-defined endpoint.

Rather than overriding **ExecuteAsync** the recommended approach is to implement [IMessageFactory](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Messaging/IMessageFactory.cs) which is what gets called if an `IMessageFactory` has been registered in the AppHost IOC. If an IMessageFactory wasn't registered than it just gets executed Sync - at which point if you still wanted it non-blocking you would override it. The impl for ExecuteAsync is at:

```
// Persists the request into the registered message queue if configured, 
// otherwise calls Execute() to handle the request immediately.
// 
// IAsyncService.ExecuteAsync() will be used instead of IService.Execute() for 
// EndpointAttributes.AsyncOneWay requests
public virtual object ExecuteAsync(TRequest request)
{
    if (MessageFactory == null)
    {
        return Execute(request);
    }

    BeforeEachRequest(request);

    //Capture and persist this async request on this Services 'In Queue' 
    //for execution after this request has been completed
    using (var producer = MessageFactory.CreateMessageProducer()) {
        producer.Publish(request);
    }

    return ServiceUtils.CreateResponseDto(request);
}
```

IMessageFactory (client)/IMessageService (server) is apart of ServiceStack's Messaging API which allows you to publish messages for deferred execution later. See the [Redis and Messaging wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis) for an example of an end-to-end solution that uses the built-in Redis IMessageService. There are also [InMemory](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Messaging.Tests/TransientServiceMessagingTests.cs) and [RCon](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/Messaging/Rcon) IMesssageService's available and it should be easy to create your own as well.

#### Future Async support

There is also an [async branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/async) that has ServiceStack running on `IHttpAsyncHandler` and already has a functional alpha build available for you to try at: [ServiceStack-v4.00-alpha.zip](https://github.com/downloads/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack-v4.00-alpha.zip)

With this change ServiceStack supports `Task<>` as a return type on services. You only need to register the [Task<> plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/async/tests/ServiceStack.Plugins.Tasks.Tests/TaskServiceTest.cs#L46). To see a full example look at [this integration test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/async/tests/ServiceStack.Plugins.Tasks.Tests/TaskServiceTest.cs).

Comment: It is possible to acheive what the Task<> plugin will allow (delayed return types without thread blocking), using the IMessageFactory approach? I have tried to understand all the examples, and I only see "fire and forget", not "fire and respond later".

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned in this answer that InMemory implementation of MessageFactory is not async, but sync, at least for version v3.9.70

Comment: The InMemory implementation is not async and there is no documentation or examples for the Task<> plugin - is it possible to "fire and forget" through ServiceStack mechanisms?