# ServiceStack and support for async / await on the server?

Tags: c#, servicestack, async-await

Is it possible to take advantage of async/await on the ServiceStack's server methods? Googling brings up a [fork of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/async) which seems to do the trick but it hasn't been updated for few months and there is no info if that code has been merged into the current official version (v3.9.32).

I built a simple service using the async / await pattern and it doesn't behave correctly but I wonder if this is just a configuration issue. Here's the code:

```
public class PodcastService : Service
{
    public async Task<object> Get(Podcast request)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var data = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.fi");

        return new PodcastResponse() { Date = DateTime.Now };
    }
}
```

And here's the JSON the method returns:

```
{"Result":{"__type":"WebApplication2.PodcastResponse, WebApplication2","Date":"2012-12-10T17:18:32.1653985+02:00"},"Id":1,"Status":"RanToCompletion","IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions":0,"IsFaulted":false}
```

For comparison, here's the same method without any async/await:

```
public class PodcastService : Service
{
    public object Get(Podcast request)
    {
        return new PodcastResponse() { Date = DateTime.Now };
    }
}
```

And here's the result:

```
{"Date":"2012-12-10T17:20:23.0245677+02:00"}
```

Any ideas? Is the fork still the way to go or is the async/await already implemented in ServiceStack but requires some configuration?

Comment: The first result seems to be a serialized Task object whose Result property contains the Date value. Looks like they haven't merged the fork yet. Judging from this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124091/fire-and-forget-with-servicestacks-asyncservicebase, they plan to add async support in v.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the project status [here](https://trello.com/board/servicestack-features-bugs/4e9fbbc91065f8e9c805641c). The async branch is still in the "Doing" phase.

The first result looks like a serialized Task object, so they definitely haven't added async service support yet.

**UPDATE**

We can forget about the async/await fork [as ServiceStack goes commercial](https://plus.google.com/+DemisBellot/posts/g8TcZaE7bv9) and gets a breaking rewrite for v4. The latest available version, v3.9.62 is a [feature-freeze version](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes) as development switches to v4.

Comment: Still looks like its in the "Doing" phase...darn

Comment: Actually, this was dropped completely. In fact, [ServiceStack goes commercial and v4 will be rewritten](https://plus.google.com/+DemisBellot/posts/g8TcZaE7bv9) - but it will include Task support.